# ionic mwl-calendar-month-view angular-calendar apply click function to specific day of month

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, calendar

I am new about development with ionic. I am using ionic version 2, angular version 4+. Here is my problem. I have a calendar in my home page. By clicking a specific day in calendar, I want to create an alert popup which contains that specific day info (day-month-year). I can create alert popup but it shows same day info every time. Some code pieces:

**home.html**

```
<mwl-calendar-month-view 
class="calendar-comp" 
[viewDate]="date" 
[weekStartsOn]=1
(click)="temp(date)">
```

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit{

date = new Date(Date.now());

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

ngOnInit(){

}

temp(param){
alert(param);
}
}
```

**library**

```
npm install --save angular-calendar
```